# I can't catch the value of my input when I load window using JavaScript DOM

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, dom-events, local-storage

I have to save the data from a form in locaStorage when I load the window.
The problem is that when I use the "load" event, I cant catch the value of the input, gives me null. And if I change the "window load" event to the "click" event the button in the form, works fine.

HTML

```
<form id="contact-form" action="https://formspree.io/f/xbjenldv" method="POST">
     <input id="name" class="input-form" name="name"  type="text" required>
     <button id="submit" type="submit">Get in touch</button>
 </form>
```

JS

```
window.onload = () => {
 const name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
 localStorage.setItem('formInfo', JSON.stringify(name));
 const showInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formInfo'));
 console.log(showInfo);
 };
```

I write 'Bianca' in the input, and  when I load the window`name` is empty. I need that `name` value be 'Bianca'.

Comment: I am not sure how you think you are going to read a value when page loads when the user has not inputed anything. You need to set localstorage when they change the input (or submit the form) and onload you READ the localstorage.

Comment: If you fill the input with te word 'Bianca'  and load the page again the value of the input is empty, but this is how the Web Pages usually works, if you want to have the previous value of the input save it before load the page again and request it from where you save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's read what your code is doing out loud.

1. Onload we run this code
2. We read the value of the input which is a value at that moment in time and will not update.
3. We store the value (which is an empty string) into local storage.
4. We read localstorage and parse it as JSON. So we get our empty string back out.
5. we display the empty string.

No where in your code do you read the text that the user enters after the inputed it. The value is just the initial starting value. The variable does not magically update with the new value.

You want to get the value when the user submits the form.

```html
<form id="contact-form" action="https://formspree.io/f/xbjenldv" method="POST">
  <input id="name" class="input-form" name="name"  type="text" required>
  <button id="submit" type="submit">Get in touch</button>
</form>
```

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const form = document.querySelector("#contact-form");

  form.addEventListener("submit", () => {
    const name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
    localStorage.setItem('formInfo', JSON.stringify(name));
  });
 
  const showInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formInfo'));
  console.log(showInfo);
});
```

or you want to get the value when the user inputs the text or changes it.

```
  const input = document.querySelector("#name");

  input.addEventListener("input", () => {
    const name = input.value;
    localStorage.setItem('formInfo', JSON.stringify(name));
  });
```

Comment: I am really thankful. Now,  I can understand the point. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I did an example of similar [code in action](https://codepen.io/pwener-pwener/pen/GRwmqRR?editors=1111):

```js
window.onload = () => {
 const name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
 const showInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formInfo'));
 console.log("info: ", showInfo);
};

function setName(){
  const name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
  localStorage.setItem('formInfo', JSON.stringify(name));
}
```

```html
<input id="name" class="input-form" name="name"  type="text" required>
<button onClick="setName()">Get in touch</button>
```

I believe the issue lies in your form or another function not properly updating the value in local storage. As demonstrated in the example, please attempt to invoke a function that will update the input value accordingly.

Comment: I understand, but I don't know why I doesn't work with the load event. I need that works when I load the webpage, not when I click on the button for submit.

Comment: Because when the page is loaded, the value of input is by default empty.  So, you need to set this in some way. It is possible to use the property value in the input, to set a default value.

Comment: Consider to see onchange event on the input. This will be trigger while you are typing.

Comment: Phelipe I try with "change" event in the input and it works, thanks, you guys!